# The strange case of "foo in bar == baz"

Tags: python

While looking through another question, a new asker used an expression of the form:

```
foo in bar == baz
```

I started to explain how Python interprets that expression, but quickly realized I didn't actually know how Python interprets that expression. Being too lazy to look up the order of operations, I figured it had to be equivalent to either:

```
(foo in bar) == baz
```

Or:

```
foo in (bar == baz)
```

I discovered from some testing that neither of these was actually true. Digging a little further, the bytecode for the two parenthesized statements was pretty straightforward:

```
>>> dis(lambda foo, bar, baz:(foo in bar) == baz)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (foo)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (bar)
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              9 LOAD_FAST                2 (baz)
             12 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis(lambda foo, bar, baz:foo in (bar == baz))
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (foo)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (bar)
              6 LOAD_FAST                2 (baz)
              9 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             12 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

But the bytecode for the unadorned version is much more interesting:

```
>>> dis(lambda foo, bar, baz:foo in bar == baz)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (foo)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (bar)
              6 DUP_TOP
              7 ROT_THREE
              8 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             11 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    21
             14 LOAD_FAST                2 (baz)
             17 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   21 ROT_TWO
             22 POP_TOP
             23 RETURN_VALUE
```

From my rudimentary grasp of bytecode, this appears to be equivalent to:

```
if foo in bar:
    return bar == baz
else:
    return False
```

I'm completely at a loss as to what the purpose of this construction is. Have I stumbled across some esoteric shorthand? Is this a side effect of some other syntax?

Comment: Chained comparisons are a language feature.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, so this is the same sort of thing as `foo < bar < baz`?

Comment: It is exactly the same thing. `is` and `==` are comparison operators too.

Comment: This in particular shows how chained operators may "short circuit" computation and skip the potentially expensive `bar == baz` if `foo in bar` is false.

Comment: Ok, so it basically gets interpreted as `(foo in bar) and (bar == baz)`. That makes a lot more sense.

Comment: not really, your if-else evaluation in the question body is the most accurate.

Comment: @Aaron Well, I was applying a line from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons): "Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once."

Comment: Oh, yah.. I was thinking execution wise. (ie bytecode) the meaning is the same, you are correct